# Calculate discount on range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of cells currently showing List price. I need the end user to specify a discount they would like to see and press a command button that will apply it to the list prices.

- Range (C27:39; C41:C42; C44:45)
- Discount % (C127) - end user populates this
- Apply Discount % to the current result in the specified Range
     --- without  disturbing the current SUMIFS formulas in the range cells.

I have already created the Command Button. I understand the code for selecting a range, and populating it with a specific value, but am stuck at the next code. In my mind it should be as simple as:

```
Range (C27:39; C41:C42; C44:45) * Discount% (C127)
```

I attempted to copy and paste values from the range in another section of the workbook, apply the discount, and then paste those back to the original range cells, but then I lose the SUMIFS formulas and need those there in case the original inputs of the model change - on another tab.

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just have `=C27*C127` in D27 and have column C hidden?

Comment: because I need the result to populate in C27...this is a deal summary so I do not want any other columns. Just need them to be able to easily click a button and show the new revenue and margin at a specified discount

Comment: Ok... VBA is way overkill but you can just store data into variables, calculate and then drop them back into the cells you need to. Lunch, excuse me.

Comment: Don't use VBA at work if you can't read the code you're running. Beyond the chance of malicious code, you are setting yourself up for failure if you can't change / explain code that appears in your documents.

Comment: Wow, good to know there's malicious people out there who would do that. I understand the pieces of the code just dont know how to write them or what the language is to use. At this point I'm just going to build out the massive IF-THEN statements I was trying to avoid. Thought there might be an easier way and that I could teach myself a new skill. 
This is a toll that Sales people are going to use and the easier I can make it for them the better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range("C27:C39,C41:C42,C44:C45")
    For Each cel In rng
        if lcase(left(range(C126),1)) = "y"
            if instr(cel.formula,"C127") = 0 then cel.formula = cel.formula & "* C127"
        else
            cel.formula = split(cel.formula,"*")(0)
        End if
    Next
End With
```

Edit: I did not realize there was a formula in the cells.  The edit will place a new formula in the cells.  It keeps the old and adds "* C127"

Edit 2: Now the code will look at C126 and see if the discount should be applied, if yes it will add to the formula if not it will remove the "* C127"

Edit 3: Added a check so that the discount is not doubly applied.

Edit 4:  Now that I think of it, why not put an if statement in C137 for all three possible adjusters:

```
= If(left(C126,1) = "y",C127,1) * If(left(C130,1) = "y",C131,1) * If(left(C134,1) = "y",C135,1)
```

Then in the cells you want to adjust just add "* C137" to the existing formulas and you will never need to use vba or change the formulas.

Comment: Yes...I noticed that once I ran it. I appreciate the language you provided and understand how fits together. Perhaps I need to copy and paste the data into a new sheet for the sales people to see the output. At this point I'm just going to build out the massive IF-THEN statements I was trying to avoid.  building.

Comment: @SarahAnn I am sure the community could come up with something quicker and less time consuming, but you would need to show a sample of the data and the desired output.

Comment: Is a screen shot of the excel sheet ok or is there a different way?

Comment: @SarahAnn Screen shots are okay. But you do not have enough points to post images directly to your original post, just put them on a site then link to it from your original post.

Comment: have added the link to screenshot

Comment: So simple and so so easy - I had a feeling I was over-complicating this. Made a slight update to calculate the discounted price instead of the discount amount and adjusted the false value on the if statements. Thanks so so much for your help Scott - truly appreciate it!

Comment: @SarahAnn Glad to help, consider marking as correct.